# In deep linking in ios, How to identify which application launched my application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a Newbie here in iOS development and I am developing custom URL Scheme supported application in iOS, how do i can come to know which application called my application?

In Android there is an API called getCallingPackage(context), Is there something similar in ios also?
I tried searching on internet, but doesn't get any satisfactory answer

Comment: I suppose you can add a query string at the and of the url yourapp://someContent?referringApp=YourOtherApp and extract it from there

Comment: That's the issue , I am not making the URL, so cannot add this query string.
This other app can be any native app in iOS also, like Camera, Messages etc